# how to increase/decrease number using + & - symbols?? in php

Tags: php

How can you increase/decrease a number using the + & - symbols in php? like when you buy something and to increase the quantity there's + symbol or to decrease the quantity then there's - symbol.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: As commented below: you need to explain what you mean more clearly! I suggest you create a new question (and delete this one as it's now closed). In short, display a button, use Javascript to click the button and then updates the value in the input.

Comment: I am not sure that is the duplicate, @JayBlanchard. I read the OP and later comments as wanting to know how to implement a UI spinner widget.

Comment: That wasn't clear when I duped this @bishop. Honestly it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more precise ?
Have you try this :

```
$variable++ 
//or
$variable--
```

Comment: no I mean for example; when you want to buy something, you can raise the quantity using + symbol or decrease it using - symbol

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you refer to the manual on this one: but is hard to find unless you know the terms. They are called "Incrementing/Decrementing Operators"

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

- Pre Add: ++$i  (Adds one to the number, returns the new number if you did `$x = ++$i`)
- Post Add: $i++ (Adds one to the number, but returns the original number if you did `$x = $i++`)

Note that there are subtle differences, so if you use them in "fancy" situations (such as in while loop conditions (`while (++$i)`) you and others editing the code will understand the differences between the pre- and post- operations.

Comment: My question is more to for example: when you buy something, and you want to increase the quantity using + symbol and decrease the quantity using - symbol. like in lazada or shopee websites

Comment: OK - you need to explain that! I suggest you create a new question (and delete this one as it's now closed).  In short, display a button, use Javascript to click the button and then updates the value in the input.

Comment: yeah I cant ask new question and have to ask new questions in two days